# Integrate GA360 with SFMC for Customer Retargeting

Tags: marketing-cloud, google, google-analytics

When we integrate Marketing Cloud with GA360, is it possible to target subscribers in a data extension with DV360 audience?

We need a connection from Marketing Cloud to DV360.

Answer (score 1):

The GA360 integration with SFMC has two parts.

1. [Syncs audiences](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai_audience_activation.htm&type=5) from GA360 to be used as an entry source for a Journey when the subscriber/contact is matched in GA360 with the `sfmc_id` utm string
2. [View Analytics within JB](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai_google_analytics_dashboard.htm&type=5) populated from properties/views from GA360

Outside of these two use cases, you would need to use the SFMC API to integrate other outside data